# Applescript to replace string using sed

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, homebrew, macos

I need and Applescript to replace some text as follow:

Original text:

```
 string  string  string  $  text1
 string  string  string  $  text2
 text3
 string  string  string  $  text4
```

The required output is:

```
$ text1
$ text2
text3
$ text4
```

I can do it in the terminal with this command:

```
$ echo "string  string  string  $  text1
string  string  string  $  text2
text3
string  string  string  $  text4" | sed -r 's/^(.*)\$ ?(.) (.*)$/$ \3/g'
$ text1
$ text2
text3
$ text4
```

By the way, i'm using bash version 4.3.30 and sed 4.2.2, both from homebrew.

The issue here is that I need to do it from an applescript. This is my approach:

```
set commandString to "echo \"string  string  string  $  text\" | sed -r 's|^(.*)\\$ ?(.) (.*)$|$ \\3|g'" as string
set formattedCode to do shell script commandString
```

And I get the following error:

```
error "sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]" number 1
```

If I remove the `-r` option, I get a different error:

```
sed: 1: "s|^(.*)\$ ?(.) (.*)$|$  ...": \3 not defined in the RE
```

If I remove the `\3`, the output must be `$` instead of `$ text`, but `sed` command do nothing and it outputs:

```
string  string  string  $  text
```

I supposed that this might be a problem with `sed` version. So, If I replace `sed` with `/usr/local/bin/sed` it does nothing again after line `set formattedCode to do shell script commandString`.

Someone know where the problem is?

Comment: The command in the applescript does not recognise the  . Also you use the -E option for extended RegEx. If you actually remove the last one you get the result. But I suspect you have them there for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution 1: sed

Option -r of GNU sed is -E on the OS X/BSD sed (the one that comes with the OS, `/usr/bin/sed`). And to get rid of the encoding problem with 's, add `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8;` to the beginning of the do shell script command (see the **question** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177602/how-to-use-utf-8-encoded-command-in-applescripts-do-shell-script-on-os-x-10-4)):

```
set original_text to "string  string  string  $  text1
string  string  string  $  text2
text3
string  string  string  $  text4"

set commandString to "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; " & ¬
    "echo " & quoted form of original_text & " | sed -E 's|^(.*)\\$ ?(.) (.*)$|$ \\3|g'" as string
set formattedCode to do shell script commandString
```

Returns:

```
$ text1
$ text2
text3
$ text4
```

[image: screenshot of solution 1]

### Solution 2: AppleScript's text item delimiters

```
set original_text to "string  string  string  $  text1
string  string  string  $  text2
text3
string  string  string  $  text4"

set output to {}
set od to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"
"}
set all_lines to every text item of original_text
repeat with the_line in all_lines
    if "$" is not in the_line then
        set output to output & the_line
    else
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"$"}
        set latter_part to last text item of the_line
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {" "}
        set last_word to last text item of latter_part
        set output to output & ("$ " & last_word as string)
    end if
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"
"}
set output to output as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to od
return output
```

Returns:

```
$ text1
$ text2
text3
$ text4
```

[image: screenshot solution 2]

Comment: Is not that simple. As input I receive several lines, ones can be preceded by the example ("string  string  string  $  text") but ones can't. Because of that I need the sed command working. If I change the sed option to `-E` works on the terminal, but not on the applescript.

Comment: @jherran, I updated my answer with what seems to be a working sed solution at least on my end. If that works for you too, I can clean up the answer removing the AppleScript attempts.

Comment: Very close @Ilari Scheinin, but unfortunatelly it only works for the last line. Check my question, I updated it a bit.

Comment: @jherran, I'm not sure what doesn't work: I get the exact same output running the command from the shell as I get running it from AppleScript (what you have listed under "Required output" except that there is an extra space before text3). So, I don't know if it's the regexp that needs tweaking, or something about the connection between AppleScript and the shell. (I'm on Yosemite 10.10.1 in case that could make a difference.)

Comment: For me on terminal works as described. From the applescript just display the last line. And, yes, I'm on yosemite.

Comment: Strange. @jherran, I updated my answer cleaning it up and now both approaches (sed and AppleScript's text item delimiters) work for me. Can you check again.